# Excecution failed for task ':app:proccessDebugGoogleServices'

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, gradle, firebase-analytics

I am trying to connect my app with firebase analytics.
I have problem when Gradle tasks: `[:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]`.

I have already put `implement 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'` in build.gradle as following guide.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

gradle build finished with 1 error

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0.
```

Is anyone able to help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Change `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0`

Comment: Pleasure! you can flag up the comment if it's helpful

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, this you need to add this line of code:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

In your `dependencies` from your `build.gradle` (Project) file.

Change also this line of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2'
```

with

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
```

Comment: inside buildscript{} line ?

Comment: its already have 'classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

Comment: Change to `3.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the **same version** of **firebase** libraries and **google play service** libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.0'
```